# Refcursor in stored procedure with postgres

Tags: npgsql

I am a rookie/newbie in the postgres data access api. I have worked a bit on oracle, sql server and trying to do what i have done with those dbms 
The use is very simple
1) a stored procedure aka function with input params
2) Returning  or more ref cursors
3) Using an ent lib wrapper to use the npgsql provider/database with it
4) Doing a data adapter fill and running into the issue with some cursor de-referencing.. it appears though i am inside a tran..
5) I just want to get some simple working sample with the latest npgsql provider..

Here is my function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.geterrorcategories(
    v_organizationid integer)
    RETURNS refcursor
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $BODY$

DECLARE cv_1 refcursor;
BEGIN 

    open cv_1 for
    SELECT errorCategoryId, name, bitFlag
    FROM ErrorCategories
    ORDER BY name;

 RETURN cv_1;


END;

$BODY$;
```

The code using the enterprise lib api/wrapper is as follows.

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Executes GetErrorCategories in case of SQL Server or GetErrorCategories for Oracle
    /// </summary>
    public static DataTable GetErrorCategoriesAsDataTable(string dbKey  ,int? ORGANIZATIONID)
    {
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        Database db = Helper.GetDatabase(dbKey);
        using (DbConnection con = db.CreateConnection()){
                con.Open();
                var tran = con.BeginTransaction();

            using (DbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand()){
                    cmd.Transaction = tran;
                BuildGetErrorCategoriesCommand(db, cmd ,ORGANIZATIONID);

                cmd.CommandText = "GetErrorCategories";
                try {

                    Helper.FillDataTable(tbl, db, cmd);
                    con.Close();
                } catch (DALException ) {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        return tbl;
    }
```

The command is built as follows.

```
private static void BuildGetErrorCategoriesCommand(Database db, DbCommand cmd ,int? ORGANIZATIONID){
        Helper.InitializeCommand(cmd, 300, "GetErrorCategories"); 
            db.AddReturnValueParameter(cmd);

        db.AddInParameter(cmd, "organizationId", DbType.Int32, ORGANIZATIONID);

       db.AddCursorOutParameter(cmd, "CV_1");



    }
```

I am not getting any error. I get only 1 row back which i think is this un_named_portal_1 or something but not the results from my table which my query returns

It is frustrating as i would like to keep my application code the same as much as possible but would like to switch providers at run time. I am using a tweaked 'ent lib' contribution database that was created for npgsql.

Hope this helps to point me to the right areas to look for..

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no reason above to declare your PostgreSQL function to return a cursor - you can simply return a table, see [the PostgreSQL docs for more info](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html).

Npgsql originally had a feature where it automatically "dereferenced" cursors returned from functions, but this has been removed. For more information about this see [this issue](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/438) (warning, it's long...). Some people are requesting that the feature be returned.

Comment: Well.. I tried rewriting it as a table and it works however it appears the return table needs to specify the shape of data coming back in the sproc signature..like this RETURNS TABLE(errorcategoryid integer, name character varying, bitflag smallint) .. Besides .. it may not work for large resultsets ..

Comment: Yes, you need to find to define the shape of the data, why is that an issue for you? And why do you think it may not work for large resultsets?

Comment: That issue reading it made it very interesting. It is very time consuming to migrate ref cursors to 'tables' to avoid this peculiar behavior of npgsql

Comment: Please add support for the pre 3.2x driver behavior of refcursors. It is just painful for our use to define the shape of the data for each and every resultset that comes back. Annoyance more than anything. Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Also, please let me know how one can use execute a sproc,return a .net dataset from a sproc that returns multiple refcursors using data adapters since returning multiple tables in postgres is not allowed

Comment: The fact that you need to define the shape of the data when returning a table from a PostgreSQL function isn't a good reason to add refcursor dereferencing - this is just the way things are done in PostgreSQL (and IMHO it's legitimate to ask users to define function return values). Note also that the dereferencing slows down your application, adding another network roundtrip to fetch the results. It's exactly this kind of hidden slowdown that I prefer to avoid.

Comment: Regarding the 2nd question, nothing is stopping you from returning multiple refcursors from your function, and then manually fetching those cursors' results. It's true that this is more manual work than a dataset that is returned as-is with multiple datasets though. I'd suggest that at least for now you can have a helper function that does this for you, it's trivial to write (see [this issue](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/438)) for examples.

Comment: Imagine that you have to work with existing database which you just cannot change. And it uses procedures returning refcursors. It's a valid language construct after all. And more than that, people usually avoid returning tables from procedures, for it causes in-memory buffering of whole table.